# Create a vector of N digits starting from K and with the step S?

Tags: arrays, matlab, range

I'm trying to create a vector of a specified size, the numbers of which would start from value K and increase/decrease with the specified step. I have to only use `:` operator.

Here's an example:

```
vector_dimension = 5;
start_value = 1;
step = 4;

last_number = ??

vector = start_value:step:(?last_number?)

% outputs: 1 5 9 13 17
```

The important thing is that the step can be either positive or negative.

So, basically, I just need to find the largest/smallest value of the range.

I tried doing things like this:

```
if (step >= 0)
    vector = start_num:step:vector_dimension*step-1;
else
    vector = start_num:step:(vector_dimension/step)+vector_dimension+1;
end
```

but this doesn't work correctly for far too many cases.

---

Does anybody have any ideas on how to implement that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
vector = start_value + (0:vector_dimension-1)*step
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically everything relies on the following formula. If the step `S`, the start value `s` and the number of points `n` are known, you can evaluate the step `S` as:

```
S=(f-s)/(n-1)
```

where `f` is the last number (unknown).
By inverting such formula you find `f` as:

```
f=S*(n-1)+s
```

in your case `f=4*(5-1)+1=17`.
Once `f` is known you can apply the usual syntax `vector=s:S:f`.